# How to downgrade Angular project version from 12.2.5 to 12.2.1?

Tags: angular, package.json

I have an Angular project with version 12.2.5. We are using a Micro Front-End Architecture. All the other Angular projects are using version 12.2.1. The project I have is using 12.2.5. Some of the css and animations are not working properly. Is there a way to downgrade it to 12.2.1. My pacakage.json file is below.

```js
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-architects/module-federation": "^12.5.0",
    "@angular-architects/module-federation-runtime": "^12.5.0",
    "@angular/animations": "12.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "12.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "12.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "12.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "12.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.6",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "raleway-webfont": "^3.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^12.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.5",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "12.4.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.4.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.4.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "12.4.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.4.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.2.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.28.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.28.2",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "typescript": "4.3.5",
    "webpack": "^5.52.1"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "webpack": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1-You have to clear the node_modules folder (make a backup if you can)

2-In the package.json file specify the version number you desire for all angular packages

```
  "@angular/cli": "12.2.1"
```

3- Run npm install command

Comment: only changing angular cli version is enough

Comment: you have to do it for the rest of packages as well, angular cli is just a package I stated to demonstrate

Comment: this is right but  I also wrote for all angular packages !!