# How to create a angular 9 application?

Tags: angular

I wanted to create angular 9 application. What I did was

1. Create a empty folder
2. Install angular CLI version (npm i @angular/cli@9)
3. in same path create application (ng new testApp)

inside new app still have angular version 15. How can I fix this

[Outside the new app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6sFV.png)

Comment: Why would you want to create a new app using a version of angular that is [no longer under support](https://angular.io/guide/releases#actively-supported-versions)?

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular/cli@9
```

Comment: I dont want to change the globel version

Comment: try to change angular cli version from package.json
check this answer here please:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69976148/how-to-downgrade-angular-project-version-from-12-2-5-to-12-2-1