# Local Angular version is lower than project version

Tags: angular, npm

i have been trying to customize my angular cli since a package only works with an earlier angular version. globally my anuglar version is 15.2.9. now when i run `ng new` and create a new angular project i see @angular/cli 16 in my package.json though. how can i bring this to 15.2.9?

The following similar question did not help:
[How to downgrade Angular project version from 12.2.5 to 12.2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69976148/how-to-downgrade-angular-project-version-from-12-2-5-to-12-2-1)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global Angular CLI version greater than local version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525746/global-angular-cli-version-greater-than-local-version)

Comment: If you use windows try to install nvm-windows (node version manager) to switch from one node version to another one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-windows. If you use ubuntu or mac, just type in google 'nvm'. It does same thing but instalation is easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this Angular compatibility [table](https://angular.io/guide/versions#actively-supported-versions), you need to ensure that your NodeJS version is 18.10. Then you will be able to generate a new Angular project with 15.2 version. I tried it out myself & it works.

---