# How to downgrade angular project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I need to downgrade my angular project from 16.2.x to 16.1.x.
I installed angular globaly and this is ng version output:

```
 cli: 16.1.8
 node: 18.10.0.
```

I've already tried deleting the node modules folder and using npm install @angular/cli@16.1. However, I get these errors:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: todo-client@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: zone.js@0.14.2
npm ERR! node_modules/zone.js
npm ERR!   zone.js@"~0.14.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer zone.js@"~0.13.0" from @angular/core@16.2.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"^16.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"16.2.12" from @angular/animations@16.2.12
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"^16.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\matmi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\matmi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-12-13T22_45_06_528Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69976148/how-to-downgrade-angular-project-version-from-12-2-5-to-12-2-1  This works most of the time. but it can still cause trouble. You can try the loooong way. Which is to create a new project with correct cli version and same name. and install main dependencies one by one.

Answer (score -1):

Edit the package.json file as in the below code.

```
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
```

then delete the node_module and install again